# How do we set the cost threshold of parallelism value in SQL Server?

Tags: parallelism

Does this value, say 50, mean that parallelization will be activated when the 51st query comes?

Answer (score 2):

> Does this value, say 50, mean that parallelization will be activated when the 51st query comes?

No, queries across different sessions are all running concurrently already, that's unrelated to query parallelism, and has nothing to do with Cost Threshold for Parallelism. Rather, Cost Threshold for Parallelism is the threshold for parallelism at the individual query level itself.

When you execute a query, the engine analyzes a series of potential serial execution plans that are applicable to that query. When the estimated cost of the *cheapest* serial plan exceeds the Cost Threshold for Parallelism, that is when the SQL Engine considers plans that utilize parallelism within them, as long as there's no parallelism inhibitors in the query, such as scalar user-defined functions.

Typically one may see multiple parallelized zones within the parallelized execution plan that gets chosen, though it's possible to have some serialized zones mixed in the parallelized plan as well, such as when a `TOP` operator, a multi-statement table valued function, or recursive CTE is used.

For more information on parallel execution and some of the inhibitors, please see this [article by Paul White](https://www.sql.kiwi/2011/12/forcing-a-parallel-query-execution-plan.html?m=1).